# Bootstrap timepicker goes negative when clicking up and down arrow

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

In the input field of timepicker, initially I just need `placeholder` there and I decided to set`defaultTime` as false:

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker" placeholder="Enter time">
<script>
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    defaultTime:false
 });
</script>
```

But after setting default time to false, whenever I click up and down arrow for changing time the `hour` value goes negative. In the documenation I found nothing helpful for this issue. How do I get rid off that negative values ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going through same issue couple of weeks ago and I solve the issue by setting time to timepicker just after clicking input field:

```
$(document).on("click",".timepicker",function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var current_time = moment(d).format('hh:mm A'); // time format with moment.js
    $(this).timepicker('setTime', current_time); // setting timepicker to current time
    $(this).val(current_time); // setting input field to current time
});
```