# prevent negative time in Bootstrap timepicker

Tags: html, jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using bootstrap time picker and initialized it like this :

```
    jQuery('.bt_timepicker').timepicker({
      format: 'LT',
      orientation: 'top',
      defaultTime: false
    });
```

[image]

but the issue is it shows negative values when clicking on down arrows but i want to prevent it from moving to negative value
this is the link i got but i don't want to show default time it should be blank by default.

> [Bootstrap timepicker goes negative when clicking up and down arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024147/bootstrap-timepicker-goes-negative-when-clicking-up-and-down-arrow)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the HTML and Libraries included by you , but i have checked and did not faced any such issue  , you may refer to the following fiddle .

http://jsfiddle.net/aurhs3yj/

```
> $('.bootstrap-timepicker').timepicker({format: 'LT',defaultTime:
> false});
```